# AWSのRoute53でドメイン取得したが、ec2-...で表示されてしまう

Tags: aws

AWSの初心者です。
タイトルの通りで困っておりまして、アドバイス頂けますと幸いです・・・

Route53で独自ドメインを取得し、
あらかじめEC2で作っていたWEBサーバのIPに紐付けました。
[image: Route53のコンソール]

その上で、このURLを叩いてみたのですが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ec2-...で表示されてしまいます・・・
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうか解決策をアドバイス頂けないでしょうか・・
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

[20180815_15:15追記]
ターミナルで以下コマンドを打ち込みました。

> curl -v [http://www.独自ドメイン](http://www.%E7%8B%AC%E8%87%AA%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3)

アウトプットは以下です。
「独自ドメイン」、「IPアドレス」、「ec2のドメイン」はそれぞれ書き換えて記載いたします。

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.独自ドメイン/
*   Trying IPアドレス...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.独自ドメイン (IPアドレス) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.独自ドメイン
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2018 06:15:52 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Amazon)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
< Location: http://ec2のドメイン
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: 切り分けが必要ですね。Terminalから`curl -v http://www.独自ドメイン`を実行した結果を、質問に追記してください。

Comment: @take88 さん　ご回答ありがとうございます。質問に追加いたしましたので、ご確認のほど何卒お願いいたします。

Comment: `Connected to www.独自ドメイン (IPアドレス) port 80 (#0)` に表示される IPアドレスは、Route53で紐づけたサーバーIPと一致しますか？

Comment: 一致してるなら Apacheの設定ファイルを編集して `ServerName` に `www.独自ドメイン:80` を設定してみてください。それでもだけなら、サーバーサイドで `ec2-xxxx...` にリダイレクトしてないか確認してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route53が提供するのはDNSです。
DNSはHTTPでやり取りされるURLとは無関係です。つまりブラウザーのアドレスバーの表示内容には干渉しません。

アドレスバーがそのように更新される理由はWebサーバー側の設定によるものでしょう。Webサーバーに接続できているからこそ、そのように更新されたと考えることもでき、Route53としては正しく名前解決できています。

Comment: 早速ご返信いただきましてありがとうございます。そうなのですね。ご返信の通りだと、WEBサーバー側の設定をいじれば、アドレスバーに「www...」と表示させることが可能という理解で合っていますでしょうか。。。？合っておりましたら、どんな設定にすればよいかご教授いただけないでしょうか。。。

Comment: @mathew 質問するのであれば、質問文を推敲し、回答者が必要となるであろう情報も踏まえて記述してください。そしてきちんとした質問を行うにはこのコメント欄では表現しきれないはずであり、新たな質問として投稿すべきです。